# How to enable CUDA in eclipse without nvidia docker container?

Tags: eclipse, cuda, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed eclipse for C/C++ version on ubuntu 18.04, 64 bit

I have installed cuda 11.0.221.
nvcc and nvcc-smi works showing that cuda compiler and device driver are both installed

I have added cuda to eclipse using eclipse->help->install new software as suggested in [Nsight Eclipse Plugins Edition Getting Started Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsightee-plugins-install-guide/index.html) and [Nsight Eclipse Plugins Installation Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsightee-plugins-install-guide/index.html)

While installing it failed to install the "nvidia docker container launch" but installed the "cuda developer tools" and "cuda remote launch".

After installation, I don't see any CUDA related entry in Eclipse->Window > Preferences or Eclipse->file->new project. Images are below after the question:

My question is:
**What to do so that eclipse is enabled with CUDA?**

[image: eclipse not showing CUDA option]

Other information:

OS: ubuntu 18.04 x86_64.
cuda 11.0.221.

Eclipse information:
Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)
Build id: 20220310-1457
OS: Linux, v.5.4.0-74-generic, x86_64 / gtk 3.22.30
Java vendor: Ubuntu
Java runtime version: 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04
Java version: 11.0.13

Comment: Perhaps try an older version of Eclipse?

Comment: Also, after you've installed the NsightEE plugins - Are you asked to restart Eclipse? Do you get the dialog box asking you for permission to send telemetry back to NVIDIA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of Eclipse is compatible with the version of the NsightEE Eclipse plugins provided with the CUDA version you're trying to install for, then - after a successful installation - the `File > New Project...` dialog will have the entry `C/C++ > CUDA C/C++ Project`.

If it doesn't show up, then the installation has failed. I would guess that it might be a version incompatibility, and you might try using an older version of Eclipse (or a newer version of CUDA). Alternatively, perhaps the installation procedure got botched somehow.

Comment: How to know if an eclipse version is compatible with particular version of CUDA (in my case CUDA 11.0.221)?

Comment: @user27665: Good question... typically, the last Eclipse version before a given release of CUDA should be safe. Otherwise, you can either ask (e.g. on the NVIDIA forums or here), or use trial-and-error. Eclipse' plugin infrastructure does not change so often, so incompatibilities _should_ be rare.

Comment: It was an installation failure. Followed the same steps again and now it works.